# integration jsf,spring,hibernate: can't call bean in jsf file

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jsf, jboss

I'm working on a project using maven,hibernate,spring and jsf(primefaces). I have a problem with the beans. In the xhtml file i can't call the bean , it doesn't recognise it. for example :value="#{collaborateurBean.listeCollaborateurs}. when i try to call it, it doesn't work. Here i just wrote even though it doesn't appear.

It seems like everything that i did is good but i don't know what i'm missing.
when i run collaborateur.xhtml i get an empty datatable.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ma.ensa</groupId>
  <artifactId>Projet_sqli</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Projet_sqli Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8-02</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8-02</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>start</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Projet_sqli</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
      </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.2" 
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="org.primefaces.spring.scope.ViewScope"/>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="model"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
</beans>
```

collaborateur.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

 <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body style="background-color: #ECF3FD;">
<h:form id="form">


   <p:dataTable id="display" var="listeCollaborateurs" value="#{collaborateurBean.listeCollaborateurs}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:10px">
       <f:facet name="header">
           Liste des collaborateurs
       </f:facet>

       <p:column headerText="Id Collaborateur">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.idCollaborateur}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{listeCollaborateurs.idCollaborateur}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Raison sociale">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.cin}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.cin}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="RIB">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.nom}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.nom}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Adresse">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.prenom}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.prenom}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Date de naissance">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.dateNaissance}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.dateNaissance}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
       <p:column headerText="Téléphone">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.telephone}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.telephone}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
       <p:column headerText="Email">
           <p:cellEditor>
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.email}" /></f:facet>
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{listeCollaborateurs.email}" style="width:100%" label="Year"/></f:facet>
           </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

   </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

CollaborateurBean.java

```
package controller;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import model.CollaborateurMetier;
import net.vo.Collaborateur;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
@Scope("view")
public class CollaborateurBean implements java.io.Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private CollaborateurMetier collaborateurMetier;
    private List<Collaborateur> listeCollaborateurs;
    private int idCollaborateur;
    private String cin;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private Date dateNaissance;
    private String telephone;
    private String email;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        listeCollaborateurs = collaborateurMetier.getAllCollaborateurs();
    }

    public CollaborateurMetier getCollaborateurMetier() {
        return collaborateurMetier;
    }

    public void setCollaborateurMetier(CollaborateurMetier collaborateurMetier) {
        this.collaborateurMetier = collaborateurMetier;
    }

    public List<Collaborateur> getListeCollaborateurs() {
        return listeCollaborateurs;
    }

    public void setListeCollaborateurs(List<Collaborateur> listeCollaborateurs) {
        this.listeCollaborateurs = listeCollaborateurs;
    }

    public int getIdCollaborateur() {
        return idCollaborateur;
    }

    public void setIdCollaborateur(int idCollaborateur) {
        this.idCollaborateur = idCollaborateur;
    }

    public String getCin() {
        return cin;
    }

    public void setCin(String cin) {
        this.cin = cin;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public Date getDateNaissance() {
        return dateNaissance;
    }

    public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

org.primefaces.spring.scope.ViewScope

```
package org.primefaces.spring.scope;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope;

public class ViewScope implements Scope {

    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        Map<String,Object> viewMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap();

        if(viewMap.containsKey(name)) {
            return viewMap.get(name);
        } else {
            Object object = objectFactory.getObject();
            viewMap.put(name, object);

            return object;
        }
    }

    public Object remove(String name) {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove(name);
    }

    public String getConversationId() {
        return null;
    }

    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback) {
        //Not supported
    }

    public Object resolveContextualObject(String key) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

CollaborateurDao

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import net.vo.Collaborateur;

public interface CollaborateurDao {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public List getAllCollaborateurs();

}
```

CollaborateurHibernateDao.java

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import net.vo.Collaborateur;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class CollaborateurHibernateDao implements CollaborateurDao{

    private List<Collaborateur> listeCollaborateurs;
    private Collaborateur collaborateur;

    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("Méthode d'initiation");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public List getAllCollaborateurs() {
        Session session=HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from Collaborateur");
            listeCollaborateurs = q.list();
            System.out.println(listeCollaborateurs.size());
            return listeCollaborateurs;
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }

}
```

CollaborateurMetier.java

```
package model;

import java.util.List;

import net.vo.Collaborateur;

public interface CollaborateurMetier {

    public List<Collaborateur> getAllCollaborateurs();
}
```

CollaborateurMetierImpl.java

```
package model;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import dao.CollaborateurDao;
import net.vo.Collaborateur;

@Service
public class CollaborateurMetierImpl implements CollaborateurMetier{

    @Autowired
    private CollaborateurDao collaborateurDao;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Collaborateur> getAllCollaborateurs() 
    {
        return collaborateurDao.getAllCollaborateurs();
    }

    public void setCollaborateurDao(CollaborateurDao collaborateurDao) {
        this.collaborateurDao = collaborateurDao;
    }

    public CollaborateurDao getCollaborateurDao() {
        return collaborateurDao;
    }

}
```

Collaborateur.java

```
package net.vo;

// Generated 22 nov. 2014 20:53:37 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import java.util.Date;



import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Collaborateur generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "collaborateur", catalog = "formation")
public class Collaborateur implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idCollaborateur;
    private String cin;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private Date dateNaissance;
    private String telephone;
    private String email;

    public Collaborateur() {
    }

    public Collaborateur(int idCollaborateur, String cin) {
        this.idCollaborateur = idCollaborateur;
        this.cin = cin;
    }

    public Collaborateur(int idCollaborateur, String cin, String nom,
            String prenom, Date dateNaissance, String telephone, String email) {
        this.idCollaborateur = idCollaborateur;
        this.cin = cin;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_collaborateur", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdCollaborateur() {
        return this.idCollaborateur;
    }

    public void setIdCollaborateur(int idCollaborateur) {
        this.idCollaborateur = idCollaborateur;
    }

    @Column(name = "cin", nullable = false, length = 254)
    public String getCin() {
        return this.cin;
    }

    public void setCin(String cin) {
        this.cin = cin;
    }

    @Column(name = "nom", length = 254)
    public String getNom() {
        return this.nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    @Column(name = "prenom", length = 254)
    public String getPrenom() {
        return this.prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "dateNaissance", length = 19)
    public Date getDateNaissance() {
        return this.dateNaissance;
    }

    public void setDateNaissance(Date dateNaissance) {
        this.dateNaissance = dateNaissance;
    }

    @Column(name = "telephone", length = 254)
    public String getTelephone() {
        return this.telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    @Column(name = "email", length = 254)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**edit**

This is what i get when i debug collaborateur.xhtml on the console. I'm using jboss 7

```
17:10:44,419 INFOS [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
17:10:44,622 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
17:10:44,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
17:10:45,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:10:45,589 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
17:10:45,604 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
17:10:45,604 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
17:10:45,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
17:10:45,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
17:10:45,704 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:10:45,720 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
17:10:45,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
17:10:45,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:10:45,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
17:10:45,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
17:10:45,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
17:10:45,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
17:10:45,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
17:10:45,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:10:46,078 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
17:10:46,145 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-6) Démarrage de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
17:10:46,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:9999
17:10:46,566 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
17:10:46,582 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
17:10:46,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found MyPro.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called MyPro.war.dodeploy
17:10:46,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found Projet.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Projet.war.dodeploy
17:10:46,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found Projet_sqli.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Projet_sqli.war.dodeploy
17:10:46,739 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
17:10:46,754 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "MyPro.war"
17:10:46,754 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Projet_sqli.war"
17:10:47,430 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /MyPro
17:10:48,853 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
17:10:48,853 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
17:10:49,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
17:10:49,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
17:10:49,275 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
17:10:49,306 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Projet_sqli]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
17:10:49,306 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
17:10:49,322 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@ccce74: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Wed Dec 03 17:10:49 WET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
17:10:49,353 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
17:10:49,696 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@ccce74]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7095b
17:10:49,759 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7095b: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
17:10:49,759 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 453 ms
17:10:49,774 INFOS [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initialisation de Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) pour le contexte «/Projet_sqli»
17:10:50,696 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
17:10:51,477 INFOS [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-1) Running on PrimeFaces 5.1
17:10:51,492 INFOS [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Monitoring jndi:/default-host/Projet_sqli/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
17:10:51,508 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /Projet_sqli
17:10:51,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
17:10:51,508 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 7401ms - Started 319 of 398 services (78 services are passive or on-demand)
17:10:51,539 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "Projet_sqli.war"
17:10:51,539 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "MyPro.war"
```

Comment: You just get the empty table, or you get an exception like `collaborateurBean` resolved to null?

Comment: no i just get the empty table. I don't get any errors. and when i try to write the bean in the xhtml file it doesn't give me suggestions so that i can use it.

Comment: Can you debug it? Does it enter `CollaborateurBean#init()`?

Comment: iedited my question and i've posted what i get when i debug

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for this problem. I had missing dependencies and i had to delete some dependencies because of problems in versions

this is my new pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ma.ensa</groupId>
  <artifactId>Projet_sqli</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Projet_sqli Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8-02</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8-02</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
  <build>
    <finalName>Projet_sqli</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```